# How to have a clean recompilation of some lbraries

Tags: unix, netcdf

I am working on ubuntu 18.10. want to recompile several of my libraries:

```
zlib, jasper, libpng, hdf5, netcdf
```

Even with

```
make distclean
```

I see that the old lib and include files still remain. Can I assume that a recompilation replaces these files, or can I remove them with sudo apt-get purge/remove ?
I am not sure whether removing them manually is safe, or will remove all of them and.or may remove other unrelated files.
I will appreciate some guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume if you have kept all the source folders and built your libraries within those source folders, then `make distclean`, if really properly enabled, will clean all the compiled stuff and you can re-build everything.

It is highly possible that `make distclean` does not clean the installed stuff, meaning if `make install` was executed and all the built executables/libraries/header were also linked/copied to the system path e.g. /usr/bin, /usr/local/ ... or whatever directories are used by the system.

Nevertheless, if you re-build everything and if again (after successful re-compile/re-build) execute `make install`, new version of the binaries/libraries/ will overwrite the old ones.

Comment: Thanks very much @msi_gerva. That completely settles my anxiety. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Calling make distclean will clean up enough that you will get a fresh compile when doing make afterwards.

The additional target maintainer-clean is available which may remove even more files, but you really shouldn't need to use it.